# Spring and Klout Api

Tags: java, spring, klout

While I can use Spring Social framework to get info referred to an user from his account on Twitter or Facebook, is there a way to get info using Klout v2 api?
Actually, it seems an http get request is necessary. 
So, how can I use my api key to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Klout API gives you influence scores and topics for a given user (twitter or google plus). It doesn't give any profile information. Need to use source APIs (wrappers like Spring Social) to retrieve those information. If you want to use klout v2 API for influence scores etc, you can use this Java wrapper - http://code.google.com/p/klout4java/